# Getting Started with Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to read and understand the code of some of the basic Machine Learning Models like Linear Regression from Python *Scikit-learn* Package, but it is too confusing at the start. Can someone tell me from where (which class) to start?

Comment: hi welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to make sure you are at the right place to ask that

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go through some courses online first, for example there is an Econometrics course on Coursera which is dealing with those concepts

https://www.coursera.org/learn/erasmus-econometrics/home/welcome

while most of the time using a full course to understand a concept feels like an overshoot, but in general it is really worth it. The courses I posted were the ones which helped me through my PhD difficulties, and gave a very good overview on not only the technicalities of the given package, but also the purpose it has to be used for.

Comment: Actually I know the basic concepts, but I just want to know How to write a good code (or writing another model using those abstract classes in Scikit-learn), thats why I want to understand the code first.

Comment: in this case take a look at this please: https://www.udemy.com/machine-learning-with-scikit-learn/

Answer (score 0):

If you know the basics and want to know about the internals (not just using it), than I would start with the [sklearn Developer’s Guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html).

It explains the idea behind the [API](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#apis-of-scikit-learn-objects), explains some of the [util functions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/utilities.html#validation-tools) that are often found in the code, to e.g. check input, and explains how [C/C++ and Cython](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/performance.html#python-cython-or-c-c) are used within the source to go for most speed - this was confusing me at the beginning as I thought it was all pure Python and did not know about Cython.